# Ubuntu : Delete part of root .bash_history without traces

Tags: root, bash-history

The .bash_history file of root may look like:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Now I delete lines 3 and 4

```
su
vim ~/.bash_history

#delete line 3 und 4 with dd
line 1
line 2

:wq
```

<kbd>ENTER</kbd> 
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>D</kbd>

But if I take a look now at .bash_history:

```
su
cat ~/.bash_history

#.bash_history
line 1
line 2
vim ~/.bash_history
```

So how can I delete only a part of the history without the last line showing I edited the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
su
 vim ~/.bash_history
```

History does not save the command if it has a **space** in front of it.

---

This is dependent on the `HISTCONTROL` variable. By default (for root) it's `ignoredups:ignorespace`.

Comment: I learned something new today!  =)  I never realized it was this simple.  +1 =)

Comment: MIght be worth mentioning that this is dependent on the `HISTCONTROL` variable.  By default (on Ubuntu, for root) it's `ignoredups:ignorespace` but it doesn't have to be.  On many systems it's empty for root (it's one of the things some admins who think they're being paranoid do).

Comment: @ssta yeah I knew there was a setting for it but forgot what it was.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned you could use a space before your command but that depends on `HISTCONTROL` variable. Here are some alternatives -

You can actually tell the terminal to stop and start recording history. It can be done using these commands -

```
set +o history      #stop recording history
set -o history      #start recording history
```

If you have already run some commands and forgot to stop recording or use space, you can still stop it from being written to `.bash_history` as long as the session is still open. It is written to the file when you close terminal session. So you can delete the current session history just before closing the session(before exiting `su` in your case). It can be done using this command -

```
history -c
```

An extreme option would be to kill the terminal process when you are done executing all commands. You basically kill the process before it can write the history to file.

```
kill -9 $$
```

`$$` will give the current terminal process id and `kill -9` will kill that process.